# SendGrid API Limitations questions

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

This document here: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/limitations

States the following:

- Unicode encoding is not supported for the `from` field.
- The `to.name`, `cc.name`, and `bcc.name` personalizations cannot include either the ; or , characters.

So I tried a test email to see what happens. I put emojis in the From name, and I sent to a To name of "John,;;, Doe;". There was no error and the email was successfully delivered.

Am I misreading these limitations? I want to make sure that what I build is correctly validating what it sends to the API, but these limitations don't seem to be correctly stated.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know exactly what the limitations are within SendGrid, I would imagine those limitations were written for a reason. It may well be the case that SendGrid itself can handle each of those characters, but the mailbox you are sending to may not. Obviously the test email that you sent handled those characters too, but that may not be the case for all mailboxes and you could cause yourself delivery problems if you try to send messages that conflict with these stated limitations.

I would stick within the guidelines for the best possible outcome.

Comment: The integration in question would be pulling from whatever is recorded as a contact's name in the CRM to populate the "to" name. So if that contact name has a Unicode character, a comma or a semicolon, we'd pass them as-is unless there's some specific reason to sanitize further.